# How to add an option for the user to run the operation again?

Tags: c, calculator

I made a simple calculator using switch case and I want to add an option at the end to let the user enter Y/N to enter new values and use the program again. I tried using do-while but the program exits before checking the condition at the end.

```
do
{     
   switch(menueNo)
   {
      case 0:
         break;
      case 1:
         result= x+y;
         printf("the result is: %d \n",result);
         break;
      case 2:
         result= x-y;
         printf("the result is: %d \n",result);
         break;
      case 3:
         result= x*y;
         printf("the result is: %d \n",result);
         break;
      case 4:
         if (y==0)
            printf("invalid denominatior");
         else
            result= x/y;

         printf("%d",result);
         break;
      default: 
         printf("invalid operation please try again.");
   }

   printf("Do you want to repeat the operation? Y/N: ");
   scanf("%c",&ch);

} while(ch=='Y' || ch=='y');
```

Comment: `scanf(" %c", &ch)` <== note the space before `%c`. It tells scanf to ignore leading ENTERs, TABs, SPACEs, ... even better, use only and always `fgets()` for all user input (contents of text files included).

Comment: If the above comment does not fix your problem, edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: So basically, pmg's remark means your program exited because it compared the `\n` that was still in the input buffer to `'y'` and `'Y'`, which was false, and so the loop ended.

Comment: Did you consider printing out the value of 'ch' to see what was actually read, or using a debugger to break after the scanf so you could inspect 'ch'?

Comment: @MartinJames the program exits directly after I enter any of the cases, while it prints "do you want to repeat the operation Y/N" it doesn't actually let me enter anything after that. Am still

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
do {} 
while (((menuNo = getch()) == 'y' || menuNo == 'Y') &&
          (menuNo != ' ' || menuNo != '\t' || menuNo != '\0');
```

since `getch()` returns an `int` rest of you code would be fine, your code will continue and remove `scanf()`;

But to get what you have to work properly you can do

```
if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
   menuNo  = ch - '0'`
```

This is because you are not reading decimal value of `char` `0` which is decimal value of 48.

To complete the answer, and point you to specific issue you can ignore space and tabs in `scanf (" %c", &ch)` courtesy of @pmg and his comment.

There is one big problem though you have to initialize your `menuNo` before `do {} while ();` loop otherwise it is UB.